# How to use AppDomainInitializer in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, appdomain, appdomainsetup

I am trying to create an AppDomain in a Powershell script. I implemented the exact same in C# and it seems to be working fine. However, the Powershell version always fails with an exception. The script code is:

```
function Execute($arguments)
{
    Write-Host "Arguments: " $arguments[0] $arguments[1] $arguments[2]
}

function Main
{
    $appDomain = $null
    Try
    {
        $appDomainSetup = New-Object -TypeName System.AppDomainSetup
        $appDomainSetup.AppDomainInitializer = ${function:Execute}
        $appDomainSetup.AppDomainInitializerArguments = @("Test1", "Test2", "Test3")

        $appDomain = [AppDomain]::CreateDomain("TestDomain", $null, $appDomainSetup)
    }
    Finally
    {
        If ($appDomain -ne $null)
        {
            [AppDomain]::Unload($appDomain)
        }
    }
}

Main
```

And the exception is:
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at System.AppDomain.nCreateDomain(String friendlyName, AppDomainSetup setup, Evidence providedSecurityInfo, Evidence creatorsSecurityInfo, IntPtr parentSecur
ityDescriptor) ...

What am I missing here?

**Edit 1:**

The issue seems to be with the delegate in AppDomainSetup, Powershell creates a dynamic method from it. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: I think the problem is because: when PowerShell (checked on v5) convert `ScriptBlock` to `Delegate`, PowerShell return it as dynamic method. And dynamic methods are not serializable and can not be passed to different application domain. This line: `AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test", null, new AppDomainSetup{ AppDomainInitializer = Expression.Lambda<AppDomainInitializer>(Expression.Empty(), Expression.Parameter(typeof(string[]))).Compile() })` crash `CSI` with same error.